# Intuition - "transfix' = to pierce?

Tags: verbs, intuition

I brook the etymology for 'transfix' = 'to pierce', thanks to http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=transfix&allowed_in_frame=0.

Yet how does this imply or induce the figurative meaning of "make motionless or helpless, as with amazement, terror, or grief"?

My guess is that if someone is pierced, then she becomes wounded and bleeds, so she is 'motionless or helpless.' Yet this doesn't explain the 'wonder, or astonishment' in [this definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/transfix?q=transfix) ?

Comment: To me the image is not of the wound or bleeding, but of a spear going right through the person and into a wall behind, fastening them there. 

Incidentally, I don't understand your word _brook_, nor can I think of anything that it might be a typo for.

Comment: LePressentiment probably means 'I accept/tolerate the etymology for 'transfix'. e.g., 'our boss doesn't brook any nonsense from his employees.' 'Brook' (v.) seems most often to be used in the negative and in Jane Austen novels. 'Transfix' seems to be solely used in a figurative sense unless one is writing a book about medieval torture.

Comment: @ColinFine How did you summon up this picture? I hadn't thought of it. user3847 is right; I want to say 'tolerate' but with a negative connotation, because I don't truly 'tolerate' it.

Comment: @user3847 Thanks. That's exactly what i mean!

Comment: @LePressentiment: I don't know how I summoned it: it is just the picture I have when you ask me to introspect on the word. As for _brook_ - I now see what you mean, but the word is only used with an object that has a connotation of opposition: _dissent_, _opposition_, _argument_. It would work here if the context had already established that the etymology in question was being presented in opposition to some other position; but without that context, it has no meaning, at least for me.

Comment: "The preserved beetle was transfixed to the back of the display."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image I get from that figurative usage of "transfixed" is exactly the same as @ColinFine's: I imagine a person who has suddenly and unexpectedly been run through with a spear. The transfixed person is frozen in place both by surprise and by the spear itself, which is perhaps still being held by the person who thrust it into the victim.

Like @ColinFine, I didn't consciously summon up this picture; it's an association that gets activated automatically whenever I hear "transfixed" used in this way.

Answer (score 1):

The root of *transfix* is *fix*, derived ultimately from the Latin [*figere*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fix&searchmode=none), "to fasten." A person who is transfixed is so absorbed in observation or contemplation that they are notionally unable to move, as if they were *fixed* in place.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, 'transfix' means to pierce--not necessarily by spears, but by some pointy shafts of varying size. I first saw the word in Roger Bannister's autobiography 'The Four Minute Mile'.
He describes a mile race in which a fallen runner's hand is transfixed by another runner's spiked racing shoe.